# When I Checkout in Git and go back to master local changes overwritten, but the folder is ignore?

Tags: git, caching

I have a cache folder, that generates cached files from time to time.

I have added it to `.gitignore`:
`cache`
`/cache`

I also used the following commands:

`git rm -r --cached cache/`

and

`git update-index --assume-unchanged cache/`

However, when I checkout a previous commit and then check what was going on in the browser, a few files in the `cache folder` are created.

When I want to `git checkout master` it fails, with the following error message:
`error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout`...

It says I have to commit or stash. But why I am not tracking....?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the `.gitignore` in the previous commit does not include cache folder. So its files are tracked and git shows error on switching away from that commit.